# Wrong Results in from LAPACK in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack, msys2

I installed LAPACK in Msys2 by pasting the command from this link: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-lapack. I then linked the library with `-llapack -lblas`. Everything seems to work fine, but every time I use the subroutines from LAPACK, I get incorrect results.

For example, the subroutine DGESV. I tried many different input values, but all resulted in incorrect answers. Does anyone know why I'm getting these results?

I've tried different values (different matrices) and I've searched for answers online, without succes.

relevant Code:

```
 call DGESV(N, 1, K, N, U_step, FRes, N, info)
 if (info /= 0) then
        write(*,*) "Error while Solving Matrix"
        stop
 end if
```

- K is a quadratic Matrix (N x N)
- U_step is the result vector
- FRes is the right side Vector

Basically in the Form A*x = B --> K*U_step = FRes

Example of wrong results:

K = [image: Picture of Matrix]

FRes = [image: Picture of FRes]

[image: Result From LAPACK and Result From Matlab]

I just didn't  trusted Matlab, I crosschecked the results in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , particularly the section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Without showing us your code, your results, and explaining why you think they are wrong we can't help you

Comment: @IanBush, I put more Information into my post. I hope That It's now enough. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You should show more code, see [mcve]. Show the declarations of all variables and arrays that appear in the code line you showed and show how you set the values of those variables. I also highly suggest taking the [tour].

Comment: Please show enough code to run your program, not just a snippet. Also, provide a means of getting that input matrix. BTW, that matrix looks as if it comes from a spreadsheet: can you guarantee that you actually read it correctly? (Print it out within your code).

Comment: I suggest you reread the documentation for dgesv - the result vector overwrites the input RHS, and the array you call U_step should be an integer array that will hold the pivoting information

Comment: Please do not post text information as images. Copy/paste it in the post instead, with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are visibly expecting the result in the 5th argument of `DGESV`, but DEGSV actually outputs the result in the 6th argument, hence overwriting the input right hand side vector(s).

The 5th argument is a work integer array where `DEGSV` stores the pivot indices of the LU decomposition.

So your code should be something like:

```
integer :: ipiv(N)
...
U_step(:) = FRes(:)
call DGESV(N, 1, K, N, ipiv, U_step, N, info)
```

`DGESV` documentation: https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html